# I only see a outline of a square

Tags: modeling

[image]I only see a outline of a square in my editor type area. I'm very new to blender and I clicked some thing to do this, and ctrl z doesent work. If you can help that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You are in Wireframe mode. change shading mode to **Solid**, upper right hand corner of 3D window:

[image]

.............and welcome to the forums :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the help!